# About the order of the product elements in the group

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a finite group, $a,b\in G$. And orders of a and b both divide $m$, then does the order of $ab$ divide $m$?

Comment: If $G$ is abelian, then yes. Do you know dihedral groups, it all elements, and their products?

Comment: @Groups oh, I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at $G=\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z)$, $N\geqslant 3$, take $a=\begin{pmatrix}&-1 \\ 1&\end{pmatrix}$, $b=\begin{pmatrix}&1 \\ -1&-1\end{pmatrix}$. Then $a$ is of order 4, $b$ is of order 3 (so we can take $m=12$),
but $ab=\begin{pmatrix}1&1 \\ &1\end{pmatrix}$ is of order $N$, in general $N\nmid 12$.

This example comes from if $G=\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$, $a,b$ the same, then $ab$ is of infinite order. (In fact two torsion elements $a,b$ generates $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb Z)$)

BTW, I must admit that the answer of @Groups is simplest.